# Temporarily disabled NSArrayController filterPredicate, or consult ManagedObjectContext?

Tags: cocoa, core-data, nsarraycontroller

I have an NSArrayController which is bound to a class in my Managed Object Context. During runtime the NSArrayController can have a number of different filter predicates applied. At certain intervals, I want to iterate through my NSArrayController's contents regardless of the filter predicate applied to it.

To do this, I set the filterPredicate to nil and then reinstate it after having iterated through my array. This seems to work, but I'm wondering if it's best practice? Should I instead be polling my Managed Object Context manually?

```
NSPredicate *predicate = nil;
predicate = [myArrayController filterPredicate];
[myArrayController setFilterPredicate:nil];
for(MyManagedObject *object in [myArrayController arrangedObjects]) {
    // ...
}
[myArrayController setFilterPredicate:predicate];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're only interested in getting all Foo instances with no filter then iterating through them programmatically, why not [use an NSFetchRequest](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdFetching.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002484-SW1) directly?

It's easy enough to use sort descriptors in your fetch request if you're asking for your controller's -arrangedObjects for that alone.

Answer (score 5):

You can retrieve all the content from an array controller, independently of the filter predicate applied, using the `content` selector:

```
[myArrayController content]
```

You don't need to reset the filter predicate at all.